# Custom numeric decimal format

Tags: .net, vb.net, formatting, tostring, numeric

### Problem:

I would like to format a `Double` number with undetermined decimal precisión (eg. `value.ToString("n2")` ) but eliminating/discarding the decimals in case of all the decimals are **0**, 
or in other words, return an integer string instead of a decimal string in case of all its decimals are zeroes.

### Question:

How I could solve the decimal formatting problem explained above?. (please, see the **Remarks**)

### Expected Results:

This code will produce the string `1,00`, but it should produce the string `1`:

```
Dim value As Double = 1.0R
Dim format As String = value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat)
Debug.WriteLine(format)
```

This code will produce the string `1,01`, doesn't need changes because it has a non-zero decimal:

```
Dim value As Double = 1.01R
Dim format As String = value.ToString("n2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat)
Debug.WriteLine(format)
```

Just another example of the expected formatting with a decimal precision of 2:

```
1
1,01
...
1,09
1,10 - Note the last zero is not eaten.
1,11
...
2
```

### Research:

I've been reading these docs on **MSDN** but I didn't seen how to solve that.

**[Double.ToString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)**

**[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**[NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** .

### Remarks:

· I'm looking for the proper and efficient way to do this, I'm aware of doing a `Substring` or things like that on the resulting string to search or count the resulting zeroes.

· I would like to keep using my current culture's `NumberFormat`, if that matters.

· I will clarify that in my real scenario I'm using random numbers then I can't know whether the value to format will have zero decimals (1,00) or non-zero decimals (1,99) and/or its decimal precision/length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `"0.##"` as your format string:

```
Dim values = {1.0000R, 1.0R, 1.1R, 1.100R}
For Each value in values
    Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat))
Next
```

Output will be `1`, `1`, `1.1` and `1.1`, which seems to be what you want (the loss of precision may or may not be what you want).

This is a custom numeric format with digit placeholders, as shown here: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).

An alternative are the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx); especially the [general format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString), which you can use without a precision specifier (which may or may not be what you want).

---

In response to your edit/comment:

There's no simple single format string you can use, but you could use a simple workaround like this:

```
value.ToString(If(Math.Abs(value mod 1) < Double.Epsilon, "0", "0.00"), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not produce the expected result, for example with `1,10`, it eats the last `0`. I've updated my question with another example of the expected results.

Comment: I can't do that, my numbers are very big (petabyte calculations), seems a good approach but converting to a numeric datatype with less capacity than `Double` will produce an overflow, it could be solved?

Comment: I still getting zeroes for decimals which are all zeroes, this is a debug output from my code: `1099511727776 Bytes rounded to 1,00 TeraBytes` I'm using your last code-formatting update, it should format that `1,00` as `1` :(

Comment: Your last code update is seems to return the same formatting as just doing an `"N2"`, but no matter, thanks for your time, I resign to perform a substring or `like` operator.

Comment: Really? Seems to work fine. Check it here: [https://dotnetfiddle.net/SoSCmR](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SoSCmR)

Comment: See what happens with "1.001" value, it returns a "1.00" string

Comment: I thought you always have 2 decimals places? "0.00" will trim the nunber down to two decimal places. If you want more, but 2 at least, use "0.00##########".

Answer (score 1):

```
value.ToString("G2")
```

this should work

Comment: I noted that I should increment +1 the precission of "G" comparing to "N" formatting, your answer is good when +1 incremented it produces in a simpler way the same results of @sloth answer, but it has the same disadvantage, it eats any last zeroes.